# Open Office 4.0 for 32-bit architecture

Tags: software-installation, openoffice.org

Apache is launched Open Office 4.0 stable version and Open Office 4.1 beta version. I downloaded both version and try to install stable version in my Ubuntu 12.10 LTS edition.

After running the `dpkg -i *.deb` command all packages does not match the architecture of my ubuntu because my Ubuntu is 32 bit and package is 64 bit. But downloaded package says that its for both architecture 32 bit or 64 bit.

Name of the package : [Apache_OpenOffice_4.0.1_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz](http://archive.apache.org/dist/openoffice/4.0.1/binaries/en-US/Apache_OpenOffice_4.0.1_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz)

So what can i do to install the open office 4.0.1 in my 32 bit system.

I don't want to use 64 bit dependencies for AOO 4.0.1 64 bit in my ubuntu OS.

Help Me guys

Update:

Desktop Integration shows error
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openoffice4.0-debian-menus_4.0-9714_all.deb

Answer (score 0):

There is 32-bit version of the Open Office in the same directory. Just download file [Apache_OpenOffice_4.0.1_Linux_x86_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz](http://archive.apache.org/dist/openoffice/4.0.1/binaries/en-US/Apache_OpenOffice_4.0.1_Linux_x86_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz), untar and install.

After installation, create files like this `~/.local/share/applications/openoffice-writer.desktop` for Writer, Calc, Draw, Impress and others:

```bsh
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Icon=openoffice-writer
Type=Application
Categories=Office;WordProcessor;X-Red-Hat-Base;X-MandrivaLinux-Office-Wordprocessors;
Exec=openoffice --writer %U
Name=OpenOffice Writer
GenericName=Word Processor
Comment=Create and edit text and graphics in letters, reports, documents and Web pages by using Writer.
StartupNotify=true
X-GIO-NoFuse=true
Keywords=Text;Letter;Fax;Document;OpenDocument Text;Microsoft Word;Microsoft Works;Lotus WordPro;OpenOffice Writer;CV;odt;doc;docx;rtf;
InitialPreference=5
StartupWMClass=openoffice-writer
X-KDE-Protocols=file,http,smb,ftp,webdav
```

Comment: Thnx man ..... !!!

Comment: @Umyhacker: If my answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Comment: KK... after the installation successfully. I am not able to find the open office in my dash

Comment: Desktop Integration shows error Errors were encountered while processing: openoffice4.0-debian-menus_4.0-9714_all.deb

Comment: See the update in answer